# Update api Youtube

Tags: php, youtube-api

I have a problem to adapt to the new YouTube API

part code that need to change:

//set feed URL

```
  $feedURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&q=".urlencode($busca)."&max-results=5&orderby=viewCount&start-index=".($page).$youtube_key;

   //Old -> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?vq=".urlencode($busca)."&max-results=5&orderby=viewCount&start-index=".($page).$youtube_key
```

//read feed into SimpleXML object

```
  $sxml = @simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
  if(count($sxml->entry) > 0){
```

//iterate over entries in feed

```
  foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
```

//get nodes in media: namespace for media information

```
  $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
```

//get video player URL

```
  $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
  $watch = $attrs['url']; 
  $watch = explode('v=',$watch);
  $watch = $watch[1];
  $watch = explode('&',$watch);
  $watch = $watch[0];
```

//get video thumbnail

```
  $attrs = $media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes();
  $thumbnail = $attrs['url'];
```

//get  node for video length

```
  $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
  $attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
  $length = $attrs['seconds'];
```

//get  node for viewer statistics

```
  $yt = $entry->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
  $attrs = $yt->statistics->attributes();
  @$viewCount = $attrs['viewCount'];
```

//get  node for video ratings

```
  $gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'); 
  if ($gd->rating) {
  $attrs = $gd->rating->attributes();
  $rating = $attrs['average']; 
  } else {
  $rating = 0; 
  } 

  ?>
```

//List result

```
  <a href="<?php echo $concatena; ?>escutar/<?php echo $watch; ?>/<?php echo removerosAcentos($url_bacana); ?>.html"><li><?php echo $media->group->title;?></li></a>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: For starters, the new API is not XML based, but is JSON based; what's more, some of the info (such as stats and ratings) might take a call to a different endpoint. Additionally, pagination of results works a bit differently now. And you'll need an API key to make all of these requests. It's probably best to break your task up into smaller parts and tackle them one at a time, since virtually all your code will have to change. Start by getting an API key and making sure you can get the search results, then use this site and the documentation to help you proceed through the other changes.